# Does Maz briefly speak Huttese to Han on Takodana?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, languages

Right after saying "Han, you've been running away from this fight for too long," Maz switches to something that sounds *a lot* like Huttese.

I hear it as:

> ya kee naga wanta

Which translating directly (not taking grammar into account) using this [supposedly canon dictionary](http://www.completewermosguide.com/huttdictionary.html), might be:

> There [*kee*] want why haven't

The kee (*kee*) phoneme is present in Huttese, for example in the word keepuna (*kee poo nah*), "to shoot", but I can't find a good translation for it in this context.

Maz follows this line up with, in Galactic Basic, "Go home".

My partial Huttese translation would seem to fit with what she's saying, especially if the untranslated term has to do with "home", making it something like "don't you want to / why haven't you gone home."

Given the phonetic similarity to Huttese, the fact that Huttese would probably be spoken amongst the sort that find their way into Maz's establishment, and the fact that Han definitely speaks Huttese, **is it safe to assume that Maz is speaking Huttese to Han, and are there any canon sources or complete translations to support this theory?**

Comment: *"nyakee nago wadda"* is what the script says

Comment: @Valorum Interesting. I wonder if that could be down to the script using a different romanization of Huttese than the one in the dictionary I used, Maz using a non-standard dialect of Huttese, or both. There's a good theoretical basis for believing that Huttese dialects can vary a lot, to the extent that a native speaker of one wouldn't understand another: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/71054/118617

Comment: @Valorum Does it say what language "_nyakee nago wadda_" is? Or do you know?

Comment: @CreatedByBrett I just checked the script and it doesn't say anything about the language being used - it just spells out "nyakee nago wadda". This is the script I used for reference: https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html

Comment: Very minor but maybe slightly helpful note, the two canon examples of the fragment kee I can find in Huttese are *keepuna*, "to shoot", and *keejckta*, "ejector seat", both of which use *kee* in a way that may be similar to the Chinese character, 出, "to go out from". Though it's possible this is a coincidence and the *kee* in *keejckta* is simply there because it's a phonetic transliteration from "ejector" in Galactic Basic, and *kee* happened to fit the phonetic bill.

Comment: "Nago" appears in several Huttese dialogues and appears to mean "want". ("Hi chuba da **nago**?"  (What do you **want**?)) but the other words don't appear anywhere else in Star Wars lore

Comment: @Valorum yes, I think that's consistent with my different romanization theory, as I translate *naga* as "want", the same as your *nago*. I'll look into the primary sources for the supposedly canon dictionary I used for translation and follow up on this one with some more info in a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Although we don't have solid evidence that this is Huttese, we can certainly identify what languages it *isn't* by comparing them to the ones highlighted in [this video from Lucasfilm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZp8Civk2co) that claims to identify **every language spoken in the Star Wars films**, noting that Maz's sentence isn't identified as a unique language (e.g. it must be one of the ones listed elsewhere in the video)

There are 68 canonical languages spoken in the nine Star Wars films. We can immediately discount Droid languages, codes and Basic, which leaves us with 53 possibilities.

[image]

We can remove languages that are likely specialised to a single planet or group, especially where that group is not readily spacefaring (such as Ewokese), which leaves us with 41 possibilities.

[image]

We can also remove all the languages where individual words are not discernible to human ears (or at least not *easily* discernible). We can also discount Sullustese as we know that it's translatable into English, which leaves us with 10 possibilities.

[image]

All of the remaining languages are formed of individual words, are spoken by known spacefaring species and can be seen in use in multi-cultural settings like Coruscant or spacer cantinas; **Clawdite, Imroosian, Azumel, Corellisi, Huttese, Ubese, Uthuthma, Jablogian, Jawren, Abednedish, Taarja, and Cloddogran.** Of these we can discount [Corelissi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Old_Corellian) (an extinct language) and [Clawdite](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Clawdite) (used exclusively by Clawdites between themselves) which leaves us with 8 languages that we either don't know enough about to discount, or where they're genuine candidates because they're well-known trade languages.

Frustratingly, none of the words used by Maz have appeared in any other of the films so we're left with guesswork. Huttese is certainly the most *likely* choice given that Huttese is the [second most common language in the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_galaxy/Legends#:%7E:text=The%20second%20most%20common%20language%20was%20Huttese%2C%20expanded%20through%20the%20criminal%20and%20financial%20activity%20of%20the%20Hutts%2C%20and%20so%20it%20was%20adopted%20throughout%20the%20Outer%20Rim%20Territories%20by%20other%20species%20that%20were%20in%20close%20cooperation%20with%20them%20throughout%20the%20ages%2C%20such%20as%20the%20Rodians%20and%20the%20Toydarians.%5B41%5D), [Han canonically speaks Huttese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BYD08tZOlI) and Maz has hired a band to sing [Huttese songs](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jabba_Flow) in her castle, which would suggest that she speaks it too.

---

For the record, the [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) states that Maz is saying is

> "nyakee nago wadda"

Which doesn't translate into *anything* using [Wermo's Guide to canonical Huttese](http://www.completewermosguide.com/huttdictionary.html).

That doesn't mean that this *isn't* Huttese, just that we've not heard these particular words before.

Comment: No, there are at least 6 million languages, (which C-3PO is fluent in) and probably a lot more.

Comment: @Spencer - Yes, but we only see (or rather *hear*) 68 of them. Maz's has to be one of those since if she was speaking an unknown 69th language, the Lucasfilm video would have identified it for us.

Comment: Still, it needed to be pointed out. The writers could have made up some throwaway nonsense words and never named the "language" they belonged to.

Comment: @Spencer - To my understanding, every single language spoken in the films has been given a name. Where they weren't *originally* named, Lucasfilm named them for that video. Something similar happened with the '*Every spaceship in the films*' video, where several new ship names were revealed.